# SQL Server 2008 R2 - DROP COLUMN, INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS and IF EXISTS

Tags: sql-server-2008, information-schema

I have a column that is functionally a duplicate of another column. I want to copy the value of the surplus column to the other and then drop the extraneous column.

The problem is the script is conditional amid other changes to the database - I like to be able to restore the database to the exact state it was in via an "undo" script. This script and its corresponding "do" script are written conditionally so that they can be run repeatedly without error.

This particular block when executed a second time, fails with invalid column. It seems to think the column is still there even though both `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` and `sys.columns` report no column exists.

```
if exists (select * from sys.objects where name = 'flint') 
    drop table flint

create table flint ( fred int, barny int )
go

select 1 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where COLUMN_NAME = 'barny' and TABLE_NAME = 'flint'

if exists (select 1 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where COLUMN_NAME = 'barny' and TABLE_NAME = 'flint')
begin
    update flint set fred = barny
    alter table flint drop column barny
end
go

select 1 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where COLUMN_NAME = 'barny' and TABLE_NAME = 'flint'

if exists (select 1 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where COLUMN_NAME = 'barny' and TABLE_NAME = 'flint')
begin
    update flint set fred = barny
    alter table flint drop column barny
end
go
```

Why does the second block get executed and fail with 'invalid column barny'?

Answer (score 2):

Since your code is split into batches by the GO delimiters, the second block is only submitted after the column has been dropped by the first block.  The second block does not get executed but it does get compiled and bound to database objects.  Hence name resolution fails and you get the error message.  The message is coming from the parser, not the database engine.

Bizarrely, if you remove all the GOs it will fail at the second `SELECT 1..` with the same error.

Comment: Ah I had it arse about face - I was thinking it compiled OK but failed on execution because when compiling SQL Server treated each batch independently and compiled all blocks up front rather than as the batch is being executed.

Comment: Thanks guys.  In reality that block only occurs once, though.  So from what you're saying, if I execute the whole script again, the whole thing should be parsed again.  So shouldn't the parser have figured out by then that the colum no longer exists?  Especially as EXISTS returns false?

Comment: Within the `EXISTS` statement the the characters b-a-r-n-y are treated as a string.  The statement is bound to objects in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` which does exists so the compilation and execution succeed.  Inside the `UPDATE`, however, the characters b-a-r-n-y play the role of a column name.  When that batch - the bit between consecutive GO delimiters - is compiled the column flint.barny does not exist and compilation fails.  Yes a second execution will cause re-parsing.  Yes the parser will know the column does not exists.  That's why you get an error message.

Comment: Here's a link which explains the process http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/inside-sql-server-parse-compile-and-optimize.  It's old, but I took a course with Kalen last year and the basics haven't changed.

Answer (score 1):

It's to do with SQL Server batching but damned if I can figure it out why at the moment. Remove the `GO` from between the blocks and it works as expected. My guess is that the column is dropped during the second batch but the third batch has already been compiled ready to send so it only fails when it tries to execute on the server. I'm going to do some reading on this because it's a neat little gotcha.

Comment: Steve, here's another fun one which still gets me: `if 1 = 0
begin
 declare @i int;
end
print @i;`

Answer (score 1):

D'oh!  The parser is looking at the references to the removed column in the block *before* we know the result of EXISTS.  So if I use dynamic SQL, all is well.

```
if exists (select 1 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where COLUMN_NAME = 'barny' and TABLE_NAME = 'flint')
begin
        declare @q nchar(100)
    select @q='update flint set fred = barny;
    alter table flint drop column barny'
        exec sp_executesql @q
end
go
```

Thanks Michael and Steve!

Comment: Nice, glad you're sorted. I have a feeling I've had similar problems with Oracle too which were resolved in exactly this way. Your post prodded my memory a bit!

Comment: It's not consistent though.  If doing the same thing with a drop constraint or column, there's no issue.

Also - it seems to make a difference if you use "SELECT 1" or "SELECT *" in the EXISTS query.  With the dynamic block, if I use select 1 I get an error about getting a non-boolean expression where a condition was expected.  Bizarro.

Comment: Even weirder - your original query works perfectly on SQL2012 where it failed on 2008R2. I'd guess that's down to an improvement in the way SQL parses, compiles, recompiles and executes (there was significant change between 2000 and 2005 too). But I don't get any errors with the dynamic block, nor does 1 or * seem to make any odds on 2008R2 or 2012 for me.